# How can I profile Ruby code in 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, profiling, ruby-prof

What can I use to profile code in 1.9.2?  All of the versions of ruby-prof I've found segfault against 1.9.2.

For instance, when I add

```
gem "ruby-prof"
```

to my Rails project's Gemfile and run

```
bundle
bundle exec ruby-prof config/environment.rb
```

I get a segfault.

Is there a new profiling gem in town?  Is there a way to make ruby-prof play nice?

Comment: And it doesn't segfault when you don't have `gem "ruby-prof"` but run the bundle commands?

Comment: Well, if I don't have `ruby-prof` in the bundle, then I can't `bundle exec ruby-prof`.  But `bundle exec ruby config/environment.rb` doesn't segfault.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it helps but I stumbled on this which may add a bit more clarity or lead you down a different path: http://www.devheads.net/development/ruby/core/segmentation-fault-when-using-ruby-prof-and-ruby-192.htm. You may want to check out wycats' fork based on that thread: https://github.com/wycats/ruby-prof

Also, I have not tried it out myself and it may not be exactly what you are looking for but Aman of Github fame has a port of google-perftools for Ruby: 
https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb

Answer (score 2):

As @chris.baglieri suggested, you can use the `perftools.rb` gem for profiling Ruby 1.9 code.

```
gem install perftools.rb
```

Then

```
require 'perftools'
PerfTools::CpuProfiler.start('profile_data') do
  # something cpu-intensive
end
`pprof.rb --text profile_data profile.txt`
`pprof.rb --pdf  profile_data profile.pdf`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use another popular profiler tool - [MethodProfiler](https://github.com/change/method_profiler)

It's very handy to find slow method in the target class.